# how to group device name in yocto

Tags: yocto

Our company developed several hardware and having the Yocto Linux support. We also integrated other machines like rpi into our Yocto project. We have our own bbappend files that we want to make it as machine specified by adding the postfix. Thus it won't effect other machine like rpi.

For example, `SRC_URI_ourMachine += " \`. However we have several machine, how can we pack them into one like the rpi. Raspberry Pi has several modules as well like RaspberryPi, RaspberryPi2, RaspberryPi3, RaspberryPi-CM, RaspberryPi-CM3. But if you do a `SRC_URI_rpi += " \`, it effects all the rpi machines.

How can we achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can solve this problem with using - `MACHINEOVERRIDES` variable.

In Your configuration file *meta-name/conf/machine/include/machine-name.inc*
`MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "common-name:"`

Then in any recipe You can use it like this (e.g. with `SRC_URI`):
`SRC_URI_common-name = "..."`

Docs link: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-MACHINEOVERRIDES

Example in poky with *qemuall*: https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/machine/include/qemu.inc#n14

Comment: Thank you! One more question, on your example, `MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "common-name"`, what does the `=.` mean?

Comment: Well this is just prepending operation that is also well codumented in BitBake docs - http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3.2/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#appending-and-prepending-without-spaces

Comment: Actually I found for Raspberry Pi, they use the global variable `SOC_FAMILY = "rpi"`. What is the different between them? Which one is the most suitable for me?

Comment: I just be able to try your solution but it didn't work for me. It should be `MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "common-name:"`, the column **:** is needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution that is `SOC_FAMILY = common-name:`. This solution need to place `include conf/machine/include/soc-family.inc` in the conference or inc file.

Then in any recipe You can use it like this (e.g. with `SRC_URI`): `SRC_URI_common-name = "..."`